# How to disable cache for some subpath nginx

Tags: nginx, regex

I try to create a microcaching in Nginx by configuring that only valid for the subpath of some URI that will work.
For example :

> https://example.com/path/anotherpath/view/ --> Will be cached
> https://example.com/path/anotherpath/view/subview --> **not to be** cached

I have tried this but it does not come out with luck

`if ($uri ~* "/path/anotherpath/[^]+/[^]+") {set $no_cache "1";}`

And this:

```
location ~* "/path/anotherpath/[^]+/[\d]" {set $no_cache "1";}
```

If you guys have any suggestions, they will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to the question so we can see the full configuration. Without knowledge of all the `location` blocks, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: here : 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: That is output of `nginx -t`, not `nginx -T`.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it by this config :

```
if ($uri ~* "/path/subpath/(.*)/(.*)$" ) { set  $no_cache "1";}
```